# React - Module not found

Tags: reactjs, eslint

My project fails to compile and produces a Module not found error when I try to import a view `<Home />` into a layout `<App />`. Here's my App.js code

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import ReactImage from '../assets/images/react.png';
 import '../assets/css/app.css';
 import Home from '../views/Home';

 export default class App extends Component {
 state = { username: null };

 componentDidMount() {
 fetch('/api/getUsername')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(user => this.setState({ username: user.username }));
 }

render() {
 const { username } = this.state;
  return (
   <div>
     {username ? <h1>{`Hello ${username}`}</h1> : <h1>Loading.. please wait! </h1>}
     <img src={ReactImage} alt="React" />
     <Home />
   </div>
  );
 }
}
```

My Home.js is as simple as this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Sidebar from '../components/Sidebar';

function Home() {
  return <Sidebar />;
}

export default Home;
```

`<Sidebar />` looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../assets/css/components-css/sidebar.css';

export default class Sidebar extends Component {
  state = null;

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <h1>This is the sidebar</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The file structure is like so:

[image: file structure]

I would appreciate a point in the right direction

Comment: It seems fine. Are your import paths absolutely OK? Also, how does the `Sidebar` look like?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the `Sidebar` and the file structure

Comment: Still seems fine, maybe a Webpack config problem? For example `jsx` extension or image importing problem, etc. Try to narrow down the problem. For example let `Home` component renders a simple `div`, then try to import it into the `App`. If everything is OK, then the problem should be in `Sidebar` maybe.

Comment: Thanks. So the issue was with the `jsx` extension was the problem. I think it has something to do with my `eslint`. Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: Was it just a warning? How have you fixed it? Used explicit `jsx` extension? Nowadays, people do not use `jsx` extension anymore, here is an alternative solution :)

Comment: Yeah. I have fixed it. I just changed the file extension to `js`. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. Actually, this is not a real solution to your problem but if you don't need `jsx` extension or fond of it do not bother :)